# javascript - async issue - data not ready

Tags: jquery, extjs

I have an ajax function retrieving the data from the database and stores that data in an EXTJS data store. I have another function which gets called during the page load and relies on the data store having the data ready.

However, the tricky bit is that sometimes this ajax function delays the execution and the other function gets called before and fails. The `otherfunction()` is called by a piece of code inside the page.

How can i ensure that the data store always has the data when the `otherfunction()` is called?

```
$.ajax({
    url: publicholiday / GetPublicHoidays,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(attributes) {
        //loading data in a store (EXTJS Store)
    },
    error: function(res) {

    },
});


IsPublicHoliday: function otherFunction() {
    //the extjs store should be ready by now and this function uses the data from the store for it to run. 
    //success function should be called here;
};
```

Comment: Make your calls hierarchical - in other words, if one relies on the other, call it from within that method.

Comment: i have tried that as well but it still defers the execution and does not guarantee that the data will be ready. i was thinking of passing it as a callback function but can't figure out how will that work

Comment: In which case could you edit the question to show a more representative example of how the logic is structured. From the question right now it's difficult to see

Answer (score 0):

try to bind the store in the grid. On success load the store. follow the example 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1su4&view/editor